# How to make shares visible in the Windows (win7 64 pro) Network view?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, network-shares, thinkpad

OS: Windows 7 64bit Pro
System: Thinkpad x201t

I have a big problem trying to access network shares located on other windows pcs (xp,vista) and NAS System (readynas nv+) from my win7 pro 64 thinkpad.
The Shares are visible from all other PCs in my network (xp,vista,macos)

I can ping the NAS for example and I can see it in the Network overview. I can also see other Services available from the NAS, but no Share is visible there, forcing me to use http to download files.

I have tried several sollutions for similar problems allready, but none did help so far.
Even Manually connecting to a network Share using its IP is not working.

Here is the most recent sollution I did follow to the letter, which seems to be the most detailed I have read so far:

> Browse to "Local Policies" ->
>   "Security Options".  Now look for the
>   entry "Network Security: LAN Manager
>   authentication level" and open it. 
>   Click on the dropdown menu and select
>   "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session
>   security if negotiated".  Apply the
>   settings.
>
> In the Advanced sharing settings page
>   of Network and sharing center, you
>   need to have it set as Work/Home
>   profile.  Try
>
> -Enable network discovery
>   -Turn on  file and print sharing
>   -Turn off password protected sharing
>   -Use user accounts and passwords to connect to other computers
>
> The other settings such as encryption
>   I have set as use 128 bit encryption.
>
> Please check related policies.
>
> 1. Enter “gpedit.msc” in the Start Search box.
> 2. Open “Computer Configuration”/Windows
>      Settings/Security Settings/Local
>      Policies/Security Settings.
> 3. In the right pane, enable the following policies:
>
> Network access: Allow anonymous
>   SID/name translation Network access:
>   Let Everyone permissions apply to
>   anonymous users
>
> Also please disable the following
>   policies.
>
> Network access: Restrict anonymous
>   access to Named Pipes and Shares
>   Network access: Do not allow anonymous
>   enumeration of SAM accounts Network
>   access: Do not allow anonymous
>   enumeration of SAM accounts and shares

I have updated all drivers very recently and since the complicated instructions did not help so far I think I might me missing something very basic...

If some special information is needed that I have not mentioned here please post a comment.

Thanks!

Comment: In Network and sharing center, what does your current network show as?, Home, Work or Public?

Comment: It is set to Work for a while now. Before that it was set to Home - no changes. The Workgroup is the same for all my windows PCs. I do not know much about the home-network name that is used in the "Home" Setting, since this setting is not available on the older OSes.

Comment: So what displays when you click "Network" in Windows Explorer? Do any networked devices/PC's show up? Double check that Network discovery is still turned on.

Comment: Double check the Windows firewall setting for printer and file sharing is enabled.

Comment: I get 2 entries in the Network view: First on ist a Multimedia Server hosted on my NAS and the second one is a storage Device Icon for my NAS which opens the NASs admin panel if double clicked. Network discovery is ON as well as File/Printer sharing. For testing I shut down the Firewall without any appearant change. However I have not found the explicit settings for Sharing and Printing in the Windows Firewall.

Comment: Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Allow a program or feature through windows firewall.

Comment: I have tried activating some of the available Features, but none seems to match your description. However since deactivating the Firewall does not seem to improve things I would rule that option out. In addition I have deactivated my AntiVirus (BitDefender) - no effect.